# Why does node.js display same content multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a code that displays HTML document (which includes .jpg image) and a code that creates a new .txt files, saves data into it and displays it in console.

But everytime i run this code with google chrome, the data gets displayed 3 times...

**Code**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
//branje HTML datoteke
var file_path = '.' + request.url;
if (file_path == './')
    file_path = './func.html';

var extname = path.extname(file_path);
var contentType = 'text/html';
switch (extname) {     
    case '.jpg':
        contentType = 'image/jpg';
        break;
}
fs.readFile(file_path, function (error, content) {
    if (error) {
        if (error.code == 'ENOENT') {
            fs.readFile('./404.html', function (error, content) {
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                response.end(content, 'utf-8');
            });
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(500);
            response.end('Server error!: ' + error.code + ' ..\n');
            response.end();
        }
    }
    else {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
        response.end(content, 'utf-8');
    }
});

 fs.writeFile("external-data.txt", "- TEXTFILE-CONTENT\n", function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Data saved!\n");
});

fs.readFile(__dirname + '//external-data.txt', function (err, data) {   
console.log(data.toString());
response.end(data);
});
```

**Result**

[image]

Any suggestions? What's wrong with the code, why does it display same text multiple times instead of once? Thank you!

Comment: There's a request for the html page, there's a request for the picture, there's a request for the favicon… That makes 3 files. You should log the urls they're requesting.

Comment: any examples on my case? @Bergi

Answer (score 2):

Open the developer tools in Chrome. Look at the Network tab. Make the request.

You will see Chrome make *multiple* requests. For example, for `/favicon.ico`.

Each request triggers your code.

Comment: Either nothing, or pay more attention to what the browser is requesting and act accordingly.

Comment: i have no idea what u mean by that :(

Comment: Examine the `req` object. Look at what is being requested. Do different things depending on what is being requested.

Comment: i've done things differently, but if i don't request the jpg image, it just doesn't show on the page. all i get is blank window of what is suppose to b e image, but it's not...

Comment: @fox: We don't mean that you should not request the image, but that you should only call `fs.writeFile("external-data.txt", …)` when a specific URL is requested.